# How to delete a file using golang on program exit?

Tags: go

I have made a command line application where I am zipping up folders and sharing on my local server for others to download. What I want to do is delete my copy of the zipped folder as soon as I close the server. This is my code:

```
func main() {
    //flag to specify whether we will be uploading folder or a single file
    zipped := flag.Bool("z",false,"Use for zipping folders and serving them as a single file on the server.(Deletes the zipped file once the server closes.)")
    save := flag.Bool("s",false,"Use with -z for saving the zipped files locally even after the server closes.")
    flag.Parse()


    if len(flag.Args())>0{

        if *zipped{
            fmt.Println("zipping...")
            flag.Args()[0]=ZipFile()

            if !(*save){
              //I expect this to remove the file when I hit ctrl+c on cmd  
              defer os.Remove(flag.Args()[0])   
                 }
        }
        http.HandleFunc("/",ShareFile)
        fmt.Printf("Sharing file on %s:8080\n",GetOutboundIP())

        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080",nil))
    }else{
        fmt.Println("Invalid usage. No file mentioned. Use wshare -h for help.")
    }

}
```

When I hit ctrl-c, the program exits and main function closes and as a result,shouldn't os.Remove(xyz) get executed? [A tour of go](https://tour.golang.org/flowcontrol/12) says, defer executes the expression when the function returns. Here, I don't feel main gets the oppurtunity to return anything at all.

What is a workaround to achieve what I am trying to do? I have some solutions in my head like wait for a keypress etc. but I want this program to be super simple,so is there a way to delete the file as soon as the server closes/program exits without requiring any further input from me?

Comment: The `main` function is interrupted so you need to install a signal handler and call `Remove` inside of that function.

Comment: Let me look into what a signal handler is. Thanks for responding.

Comment: Here is an easy example: https://gobyexample.com/signals

Comment: Thank you so much. That link had exactly what I needed.

Comment: @squiguy In my program, i created a channel. Now my problem is, if i wait for the signal before starting the server, the program pauses,waiting for the signal and I dont know how to wait for the signal after I have started the server(nothing gets executed after ListenAndServe). This seems like a very basic problem but I am fairly new to all this. What should I do?

Comment: Alright,I got it.

Comment: Cool, I guess I should have mentioned that a channel read is blocking.

Comment: @Krash Just a question: why not consider tmp file as an option? I know the tmp may not delete immediately after you stop the program but it will delete quite soon later and save you some line of code.

Comment: @nvcnvn I am very new to go as well as developing applications. I didn't know that I can simply create a temp file. Thank you for suggesting that.It is a very decent option but I kind of want to have an option of saving the zipped files(using flags) with me as well. This would be easier if all files were created in the same manner and depending on the  flags, os.Remove would or wouldn't be executed. This question was a win,win for me, I learned two things I didn't know at all .Thank you.

Comment: @Krash you may want to consider answering your own question for future reference to others.

Comment: @squiguy I am sorry. I will keep that in mind from now on.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This has already been answered in the comments, but I'll document it here for completeness.

`defer` works only when the program and code you're using it in runs through its course normally. Stopping a program with with a command or killing it, on the other hand, sends a signal to the program and then terminates it abnormally, which does not allow the program to run all the `defer` statements cleanly.

If you want to cleanup on OS termination, you can listen for OS signals - code based on [the example here](https://gobyexample.com/signals):

```
sigs := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
signal.Notify(sigs, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
go func() {
  <- sigs
  cleanupAllTheThings()
  os.Exit(0)
}()
```

If you call this from `main`, it will keep a goroutine running for the life of your program listening to the OS signals. And the `cleanupAllTheThings()` function needs to be written to run as fast as possible without blocking to be effective - you never know when the OS is going to terminate you with prejudice.

Also, this will not protect you from someone pulling out the plug or a kernal panic - so it usually makes sense to have some kind cleanup of the old program state on startup or in a separate cleanup script.

Comment: just to mention - actual delete of file would be **os.Remove(path)**