# How to use defer in combination with http.ListenAndServe?

Tags: http, go

When using `http.ListenAndServe()` in Go, this results in a blocking situation where the application, apparently, can only be stopped by killing it. This seems to skip processing my `defer` statements. Please see the code below. When I kill the application the db is not closed. How can I make sure my `defer` statement will be run?

```
func main() {
  db := NewDB(DBFILENAME)
  defer db.Close()
  http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
  http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)
}
```

Comment: ListenAndServe blocks. `defer` is only executed if the function returns.

Comment: JimB, I believe you are describing the same problem, but in other words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`defer` statements get executed only when the function enclosing them returns. Your main function is not returning when you kill it. So you need to use signals and channels.

This is a good link explaining the same https://www.socketloop.com/tutorials/golang-intercept-ctrl-c-interrupt-or-kill-signal-and-determine-the-signal-type .

I faced the same problem with my last project. I implemented a similar solution in my project [wshare](https://github.com/Krashcan/wshare/blob/master/main.go) .

In your case, you can try something like

```
     ch := make(chan os.Signal, 3)

     signal.Notify(ch, os.Interrupt,syscall.SIGTERM,syscall.SIGINT)


     go func() {
             signalType := <-ch
             signal.Stop(ch)
             log.Println("Exit command received. Exiting...")

             // this is a good place to flush everything to disk
             // before terminating.
             db.Close()
             log.Println("Signal type : ", signalType)

             os.Exit(0)

     }()
```

Comment: Alternatively, have a look at this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41432193/how-to-delete-a-file-using-golang-on-program-exit/41455960#41455960

Answer (score 3):

The HTTP package in the next go release 1.8 will have a new Shutdown function that gracefully shuts down the server . https://beta.golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server.Shutdown
I suppose that defer will work then.